# The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, build

I have a problem when building on ios simulators/devices.

I have this message:

```
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'DKPhotoGallery' from project 'Pods')
```

I tried to:

- Uncomment `platform :ios, '11.0'` in my Podfile
- Set every platform target to ios 11 with a post install hook in my podfile like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
  end
 end
end
```

Before each try, I clean everything and delete cache and `.lock` files.

I work with a Macbook air M1.

This problem started happening a few days ago suddenly. The project worked before. Even when I erase everything and re-clone the project it's leading to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do are the following:

1. Open your project in xcode {Project Folder}/ios/Runner.xcworkspace.

[image]

2. Change the IOS versions to a higher version.

[image]

[image]

**Note**: try to revert your podfile back to its original state before doing the ff. steps above.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't worked
I tried with and without the change in the Podfile
Without the change, I have the same error and with it I have a ```Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found```